# How to add a Row_Index to a Mysql Select statement that is unique only by the data in one column?

Tags: mysql

Below is the basis of my select statement

```
SELECT id, name, data FROM users
```

Example:

```
 id    name   data 
  1     a     4
  2     a     2
  3     a     8
  4     a     5
  5     b     4     
  6     b     3
  7     b     2    
  8     c     5
  9     c     7
  10    c     2
```

I want to add a column to the select statement that will count how many times a specific data entry in column "name" appears.  I do not want to find just the total of how many times A,B or C appears in the table. I want to have some kind of incremental ID (Index),that essentially will count out how many times A,B or C are entered into the table.

```
 id    name   data  Index
  1     a     4       1 
  2     a     2       2
  3     a     8       3
  4     a     5       4
  5     b     4       1
  6     b     3       2
  7     b     2       3
  8     c     5       1
  9     c     7       2
  10    c     2       3
```

This is my first post so please let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, name, rating,
    if(@name = name,
       @idx := @idx + 1,
       @idx := 1 + ((@name := name) IS NULL)) as ClassRanking
from users cross join
     (select @idx := 0, @name := '') params
order by name, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have sequential Order of ID Column and it does not have any sequence break.

```
SELECT usr.*, (usr.id-usr_grp.id)+1 AS `index` FROM users usr
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MIN(id) as id,name 
    FROM users 
    GROUP BY name
) usr_grp ON usr.name=usr_grp.name
```

SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3545a/6